# How to get the EOF token/node from the listener

Tags: python-3.x, antlr4

Is there a way to get the `EOF` from the listener in Python ?

While looking at listener interface, I noticed `EOF` is not present, probably because it is not a rule.

In my grammar I use a standard `EOF` at first rule, nothing specific.

Answer (score 1):

The `EOF` token can be accessed in the same way as other tokens can be accessed inside listener methods.

For example, if you have a grammar called `ElixirParser.g4` that contains the rule:

```
parse
 : block EOF
 ;
```

then you can do:

```py
import antlr4
from ElixirLexer import ElixirLexer
from ElixirParser import ElixirParser
from ElixirParserListener import ElixirParserListener


class DemoListener(ElixirParserListener):
    def enterParse(self, ctx: ElixirParser.ParseContext):
        print('block:', ctx.block().__repr__())
        print('EOF token:', ctx.EOF())


lexer = ElixirLexer(antlr4.InputStream('IO.puts("Hello world from Elixir")'))
parser = ElixirParser(antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer))
listener = DemoListener()
walker = antlr4.ParseTreeWalker()
walker.walk(listener, parser.parse())
```

which will print:

```
block: <ElixirParser.ElixirParser.BlockContext object at 0x101a49b30>
EOF token: <EOF>
```